# Python RegEx matching anomaly

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the LHS and RHS of a linear equation using the RegEx matching in Ptython.

```
exp="+1-3=x+2";
parts = re.search("(.*?)=(.*?)", exp);
left = parts.group(1);
right = parts.group(2);
```

although the value of `left` is correctly captured, the value of `right` is empty.

Is there something I am doing wrong? needless to say I am new to Python.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? How about `left, right = exp.split('=')` ?

Comment: I am aware of the string manip methods. I was trying to practice RegEx in Python so wanted to accomplish this with RegEx only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the right-hand side greedy by removing the question mark:

```
parts = re.search("(.*?)=(.*)", exp);
```

Otherwise the matching stops right after the `=`.

Alternatively, use `$` to anchor to the end of the string.

Finally, it is worth noting that you don't actually need a regex here:

```
left, _, right = exp.partition('=')
```

Comment: Isn't ? used to make stuff non-greedy?

Comment: @mihsathe: Sorry, been a long day. I've fixed the wording in the answer.